# I would like to be able to ask questions again. What more can I do to improve my existing questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

As per [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), when asking questions is disabled for your account, you are supposed to go edit and improve your existing questions until the nebulous "system" (an algorithm I assume?) decides you have made significant improvement. However, all of my previous questions are pretty thorough and clearly-stated, with multiple examples where applicable--I'm not sure what more I could possibly add to them.

Is there anything else I can possibly do to improve my content in the eyes of the algorithm?  Am I just stuck being unable to use Stack Overflow for the next 6 months?

Comment: Besides improving your questions, there is nothing you can do. Have you checked your deleted questions, because the undeleted ones look fine to me.

Comment: @BDL I have 6 total deleted questions.  Two were from when I had a coding problem only to later find out that the cause was an separate issue outside of the scope of the question.  Two were from when I realized I had described a problem poorly and deleted the question so that no one would waste time trying to answer a bad question while I re-typed it. Two were deleted automatically because they got -2 points and no answer, but I thought they were well-explained questions and no one ever said why they downvoted it. In all of these cases, I can't imagine much of a reason to go edit them now.

Comment: I suppose there is something about stack exchange that I'm not understanding since this question is now sitting at -3 votes even though it seems pretty clear and straightforward to me.

Comment: "this question is now sitting at -3 votes even though it seems pretty clear and straightforward to me." Questions like this are seen as not useful on Meta because we can't really tell you much that isn't already in the FAQs and such (although I tried below) and more importantly because we can't do anything about the ban. Aside from that, we routinely get questions here about the question ban from people, shall we say, with a much less sympathetic case.

Comment: “However, all of my previous questions …” - If this were true you wouldn’t be question banned. Having 6 deleted questions most definitely explains the reason you were question banned. Question deleted due to not being improved and not receiving an answer can be undeleted if you flag the question after improving it by editing it. As for the two you deleted, you should have deleted those questions improved them, then flagged them to be undeleted. I assume you submitted 2 additional questions so you would potentially get them answered faster. This question made no mention of those deleted questio

Comment: If you look at the questions tagged [post-ban], you'll see that extremely similar questions are posted quite regularly here. In fact, two others have already been posted this week, one more was posted last week, and another one was posted the week before. That being said, the question lacks research effort, and there's really nothing we can add to what's already been stated in the FAQ. The only way to get out of the ban is to improve your posts (including the deleted ones if possible).

Comment: Also, you're *not* unable to use Stack Overflow - you can still upvote, downvote, edit, answer, read questions, and flag content. You just can't ask questions until you improve your questions.

Comment: Most notably you can still search for existing answers (although highly recommended to use external search engines to do so). It's a knowledge base, not a helpdesk. The primary use of the site is to not actually have to ask questions.

Answer (score 17):

There is much more useful information here in the comments than the question.

> I have 6 total deleted questions.

6 deleted and 4 undeleted questions is a pretty bad ratio. A net score of +2 on the undeleted questions is fine, but not stellar. It's pretty hard not to get question-banned like this.

Yes: the algorithm is severe, not known to us in detail (by design), and seems to make some questionable choices. Worse yet, this approach doesn't - **can't** - deal with the bulk of the problem, because of the long tail of users who ask a single low-quality question and never try again.

However, for those who do intend to keep asking questions, it's important to understand that the purpose of the site **is not** to provide a place to get personalized help whenever you run into a problem. Questions here need to be able to contribute to a useful, searchable Q&A library.

> Two were from when I had a coding problem only to later find out that the cause was an separate issue outside of the scope of the question.

I agree; such questions cannot be improved, and it is unreasonable for the algorithm to expect such a thing. However, we literally can't do anything about it.

The only advice I can give, therefore, is to avoid the problem in the future. Before trying to ask about a coding problem (I assume you mean that *existing code did something wrong*, rather than that you couldn't figure out how to do something) that you have a **consistently reproducible** setup for the problem that is properly captured in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

> Two were from when I realized I had described a problem poorly and deleted the question so that no one would waste time trying to answer a bad question while I re-typed it.

I agree; the system should not penalize someone for trying to fix the question this way. The worst thing that happens is that database space gets wasted on the deleted draft versions. Going forward, however: don't "re-type" the question as a new one. Instead, edit the question **in place** to describe the problem properly. It is not at all necessary to delete the question. If you happen to have done so, however, edit the question in place *and then undelete it*.

If you have deleted questions that were failed attempts at now existing undeleted questions, I would still do this, and let us know on Meta that you're doing it. We can then just close those questions, after you have undeleted them, as duplicates of the properly asked one. [After some time, those may get automatically deleted by the Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions). I am pretty sure that this is a net positive for your question-ban outlook. If not, I am that much more annoyed with the software. But that's all I can offer you.

> Two were deleted automatically because they got -2 points and no answer, but I thought they were well-explained questions and no one ever said why they downvoted it.

I agree; the system overall is dysfunctional. This time there is a social problem as well as a technical one.

Explanations for downvotes [are not expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436), and commonly not offered because people have become accustomed to retaliation. The site ought to be able to offer pro-forma objections to questions that allow filling in specific reasoning (e.g. voting to close something as unclear automatically accompanied by a statement of *what* that person found unclear); but everyone is left to their own devices (and preferences/habits) here.

Questions that were downvoted were certainly not *ignored*, so this didn't come about because of asking in an unpopular tag. If there weren't any actual close votes on the question, there probably should have been; practically everything that merits a negative question score can't be expected to meet the site standards, either. But sometimes the people who see the question aren't the ones with the reputation needed to cast close votes, and sometimes moderator flags to close something don't get accepted.

Beyond that, I can't really advise without seeing the actual questions.